# java junit has no main function

Tags: java, function, reflection, junit

I have a question when I was using JUnit 4. There is one thing really confused me. 
Why does the following has no main function, but it can be executed and give the testing result back? It does not even extend a class. So confused.... The code are as followed:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;    
import org.junit.runners.Suite;    
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)    
@SuiteClasses({ ATest.class,BTest.class })    
public class AllTests {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main method (not function) is implemented in the runner class. The runner class is invoked by the IDE or the build tool, then the runner loads the Test classes and executes all the methods that are marked (ie. by @Test annotation).

The lifecycle of a test is a bit more complex than a main function. 
You can have a preparation (@BeforeClass and @Before annotated methods) before to execute each @Test, then a clean up (@After and @AfterClass annotated methods).

This framework gives you more flexibility than just having a single main method. Also annotated tests can be ran individually: you may have a huge test suite, but you may want to run just a failing test repeatedly while correcting a bug; this cannot be done with a main method (unless you have a main method for every test).

There are several advantages in using a framework like JUnit over plain Java classes with a main, as you can see.

Comment: ok, you mean the main method in the runner class is actually implemented by the eclipse IDE or the builder tool? I guess it involves some low-level details. Where can I see the details(runner class?)? Besides, with the annotation 'Test' ahead every test, whenever i choose to build, the IDE or the builder tool will invoke the runner class's main method, and do the tests(one single test or a whole test suite) according to the annotation, right? Thanks for your detailed explanation!

Comment: no: the IDE doesn't implement anything. Here is the main you are looking for: https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.java
The main method is actually a convention in Java for starting a program for the command line; once the IDE is started by its main() it can directly use junit features accessing its API as a normal java library. Another example: to run a Java Applet, you don't need the main: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/subclass.html the `appletviewer` utility provides his own main it loads and run the applet init().

Comment: uh... I have tried to use command line to run the code above, and it showed the exception that 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main'
So, Junit is closely related to the IDE? If I want to implement a feature, (such as running the unit tests every one hour, when it encounters failures, developers will get notification emails), does that mean I cannot use the code above?

Comment: Another question is: I am kinda confused by the 'The main method is actually a convention in Java for starting a program for the command line; once the IDE is started by its main() it can directly use junit features accessing its API as a normal java library'.
For example, after I start eclipse, does eclipse load the junit? when I run my code above in the ide, how does the ide know that the main method is not needed, and it should use the main in the runner class? What are the sequence? So sorry i am not very clear.

Comment: @BaoChris  Hi, we are in 2015.. I think you have progressed a little bit in Computer Science. You should have got to know what a compiler is and what a JVM is? Eclipse is just an IDE that helps you to do some repetitive works. The core of Java Platform is always **javac** and **java**.

Answer (score 0):

It is the role of the test runner to do that. You didn't have a `main()` method in JUnit < 4 either. It is just that the JUnit 4 runners rely on annotations, while the JUnit 3 runners relied on method names.

Answer (score 0):

**IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 (Community Edition)**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

In detail, you can view the console log of IDEA. Below is the startup process of my analysis.

test class: `com.example.BirdColorTest`

test method: `whichColor`

`java -classpath "***" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.example.BirdColorTest,whichColor`

https://github.com/joewalnes/idea-community/blob/master/plugins/junit_rt/src/com/intellij/rt/execution/junit/JUnitStarter.java

`main` -> `prepareStreamsAndStart(***)` -> `getAgentClass(***)` -> `Class.forName("com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner")`

https://github.com/joewalnes/idea-community/blob/1fa2c45953ed08667da52b1b83d44c56eb83b043/plugins/junit_rt/src/com/intellij/junit4/JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java

`startRunnerWithArgs(***)` -> `JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(args)`

https://github.com/joewalnes/idea-community/blob/1fa2c45953ed08667da52b1b83d44c56eb83b043/plugins/junit_rt/src/com/intellij/junit4/JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java

`buildRequest(***)` -> `else { int index = suiteClassName.indexOf(',');***` -> Get your class name, method name, and initialize execution.

"**The main method (not function) is implemented in the runner class.**" @Luigi R. Viggiano is right!